# "much more than" vs "more often than"

Tags: comparative

> You go out **much more** than I do.
>
> You go out **more often** than I do.

Do these sentences have the same meaning? If I translate them into my native language, it seems they have the same meaning.

Comment: Yes, they have the same meaning.

Comment: Basically, but the "much" in the first sentence makes it sound stronger than the second. If you added a "much" to the second sentence (or took it out of the first), then I'd say that they are equivalent.